Mysql trigger after insert with on duplicate key
This code does not work and I can't figure out why.
I use it with OCS Inventory agent and it creates a 500 error on the agent inventory which means there is clearly a defect inside but there are no errors neither in mariadb.log neither in httpd logs
        delimiter |
        CREATE TRIGGER AUTO_UPSERT_MIDDLEWAREV2 AFTER INSERT ON `MIDDLEWAREV2`
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MIDDLEWAREV2_CDC (ID, HARDWARE_ID, NAME, TYPE, SERVER_NAME, SERVER_BINARY_PATH, PORT, STATE, SERVER_VERSION) VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.HARDWARE_ID, NEW.NAME, NEW.TYPE, NEW.SERVER_NAME, NEW.SERVER_BINARY_PATH, NEW.PORT, NEW.STATE, NEW.SERVER_VERSION) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = NEW.ID, TYPE = NEW.TYPE, SERVER_NAME = NEW.SERVER_NAME, PORT = NEW.PORT, STATE = NEW.STATE, SERVER_VERSION = NEW.SERVER_VERSION;
        END;
        |
        CREATE TRIGGER AUTO_DELETE_MIDDLEWAREV2 AFTER DELETE ON `MIDDLEWAREV2`
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        DELETE FROM MIDDLEWAREV2_CDC WHERE ID NOT IN (select ID from MIDDLEWAREV2) AND HARDWARE_ID = OLD.HARDWARE_ID;
        END;
        |
        delimiter ;

Please help !
I've tried with `` and without also tried to add spaces and lot of other syntax stuff but it did not change anything, Error 500 on the inventory and empty table.
I also made a lot of searches but did not find anything that helps
Here are the two tables definition as requested
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MIDDLEWAREV2` (
                        `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `HARDWARE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
                        `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `SERVER_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `SERVER_BINARY_PATH` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `PORT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `STATE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `SERVER_VERSION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        -- `EXECUTIONDATE` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
                         PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`,`HARDWARE_ID`),
                         INDEX `NAME` (`NAME`),
                         INDEX `SERVER_VERSION` (`SERVER_VERSION`),
                         INDEX `ID` (`ID`)
                         ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=INNODB ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;");
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MIDDLEWAREV2_CDC` (
        `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `HARDWARE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `SERVER_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `SERVER_BINARY_PATH` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `PORT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `STATE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `SERVER_VERSION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`HARDWARE_ID`,`NAME`)
        ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=INNODB ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;");

here is the result of the
SELECT VERSION(); 

statement :
10.5.21-MariaDB-log 

for the 500 internal server the OCS agent communicates with the Communication Server using HTTPS. The Communication Server uses PERL code to insert data inside the MIDDLEWAREV2 SQL Table. Everything works fine for this part but when I add the trigger part it fails and the 500 Internal Server Error is the only error message I get on the Client (OCS Agent) side, response from the Communication to the Inventory sent but it's 100% sure that the error comes from the triggers

You mention mariadb.log. Are you really using MariaDB, not MySQL? Query SELECT VERSION(); to confirm.

Please add table definitions as text. sample insert and delete statements would also help

Error 500 (Internal Server Error) is not related to MySQL.

I am a bit surprised that middlewarv2 is the history of change and middlewarv2_cdc is the current record for a hardware id , nevertheless after fixing the errors in the published code inserts works as coded in mysql standalone https://dbfiddle.uk/lxL9lYIy
